# MsalModule does not have a module def (ɵmod property)

Tags: msal-angular

```
MsalModule does not have a module def (ɵmod property)

      36 | describe('AppComponent', () => {
      37 |   beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    > 38 |     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
```

I am executing ng test command . I have tried

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

but same error